# Save the initial state of a workbook

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I would like to save the initial state of a workbook (or an Excel application) in the beginning, so that I could always get back to it regardless of modification on the workbook by my Add-in.

I tried some following code in `Home.js`:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();
            initial();
            $('#getInitial').click(getInitial);
        });
    };

    var ctxInitial;

    function initial () {
        ctxInitial = new Excel.RequestContext();
    }

    function getInitial() {
        Excel.run(function () { 
            var wSheetName = 'Sheet1';
            var worksheet = ctxInitial.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wSheetName);
            var usedRange = worksheet.getUsedRange();
            usedRange.load(["values"]);
            return ctxInitial.sync().then(function() {
                document.getElementById("area").value += usedRange.values.toString();
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

In the very beginning, my tests prints well the initial values of the worksheet. However, after some manual modification on some cell values, `getInitial` prints the current state of the worksheet rather than the initial values.

Does anyone know what's the best practice to realise this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context does not store workbook state (How could it? It's a JavaScript object that lives in a completely separate world from the document). A context is merely a pipeline (or, if you will, an accumulator of commands) of what actions to dispatch.

There is no real reason to hang on to a context object, except for using it as a way of creating two objects from the same context (e.g., `range1.getIntersection(range2)`, since objects must be from the same context in order to interact). But beyond that, the context's life can (and generally should) be as quick as possible. That's why in `Excel.run` we always create a new context for you, and dispose of it at the end.

On a related note, and for the same reasoning, it makes no sense to do an `Excel.run` and NOT use the context that it provides (or use a different context, as you do in your example). You could just as easily run your code without an `Excel.run`, it gains you nothing to have it be in an `Excel.run` block if you're reusing an existing context (and note that you won't get the automatic object-tracking that you would have with a clean `Excel.run`).

Hope this helps!

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: So, in the beginning, what should I store for the initial state of the workbook? Just `workbook`?