# How to get all used ranges of a workbook

Tags: ms-office, office-js

Given a workbook, I want to go through its worksheets and get their used range. I have written the following code, which works:

```
function getUsedRanges () {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
        var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;
        var sheetnames = [];
        worksheets.load('items');
        return ctx.sync().then(function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                worksheets.items[i].load('name');
            };
            return ctx.sync().then(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    sheetnames.push(worksheets.items[i].name);
                }       
            })
        }).then(function () {
            var usedRange = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetnames[i]);
                usedRange[i] = worksheet.getUsedRange();
                usedRange[i].load('address');
            };
            return ctx.sync().then(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                console.log(usedRange[i].address);
                }
            });
        })
    })
}
```

However, the code looks heavy to me. For instance,

1) I had to record `sheetnames` to have access to each worksheet by `getItem`

2) I had to load `items` and then load `name` to get `sheetnames`.

Does anyone know if there is any method or property that could make the code lighter? What's the best structure of code for this kind of task?

**Edit 1:** Following the answer of Michael, I still put a version which gets both `usedRanges` and `sheet names`, note that `sheet names` are not mandatory to get `usedRanges`:

```
function getUsedRanges () {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
        var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;
        var usedRange = [];
        worksheets.load('name');
        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    usedRange[i] = worksheets.items[i].getUsedRange();
                    usedRange[i].load('address');
                };
            })
            .then(ctx.sync)
            .then(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    console.log(worksheets.items[i].name);
                    console.log(usedRange[i].address);
                }
            })
      })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1) `worksheets.load('items');` does nothing.  A load on a collection should specify what are the property names of the child items that you care about.  So if you want to find out the worksheet names, you should do `worksheet.load('name')`, and you won't need `worksheets.items[i].load('name');`

2) There is no reason for you to do `ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetnames[i]);`, you can simply get the sheet from the `ctx.workbook.worksheets` collection that you just loaded (i.e., `ctx.workbook.worksheets.items[0]`).

3) This means your code can become

```
function getUsedRanges () {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
        var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;
        worksheets.load('name');
        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                var usedRange = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    usedRange[i] = worksheet.getUsedRange();
                    usedRange[i].load('address');
                };
            })
            .then(ctx.sync)
            .then(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    console.log(usedRange[i].address);
                }
            })
    })
}
```

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Thank you Michael... For [the question of yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37871688/702977), is there no way to save a global initial `workbook` or `worksheets`, so that we could later load some of its properties (eg, `items`, `name`) when necessary? In other words, do we have to load all the properties (that we will need later) in the beginning and save them in variables (like this thread)?

Comment: One thing:  I actually realized I had a mistake above, instead of `worksheet.load('items')` it should be `worksheet.load("name")`

Comment: `worksheet` is not defined, any idea how to handle it?

Comment: @iatharva, FYI that I've left the Extensibility team a couple years back -- if you're having issues, I'd recommend you ask a new question and hopefully someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Thanks, I figured it out.